# Returning a function if an element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for the most efficient way of breaking a function if a class of element already exists within the DOM.

For example, checking if a class of span exists, at the moment I'm using

```
$(function() { 
    //logic will execute

    if ( $(this).find('span.myspan').length ) return;

    //logic will execute if search doesn't find span.myspan
});
```

I've seen a few examples some using if/else rather than return. Some example that were using find() have used

```
.find('span.myspan')[0]
```

Instead of .length is there nothing to check it exists? Or perhaps a way to compare it to null?

So from within a function, what is the most efficient method of checking if an element exists in the DOM and if it does, the function is returned immediately?

Comment: Checking .length or [0] are equally fast; I would stick with .length as you used in your example because I think it's more readable, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use vanilla JS

```
    console.time('t');
    document.querySelector('.label-key');
    console.timeEnd('t')
    t: 0.000ms
    console.time('t');
    $('.label-key'); 
    console.timeEnd('t')
    t: 1.000ms
```

> [Check out jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/vanillaselector)
>   [image: jsperf test]

Also Do it the other way around. 
check if the element doesn't exist and then do stuff. If it does just leave it alone.

```
$(function() { 
    //logic will execute

    if (! document.querySelector('.label-key'); ){

    //logic will execute if search doesn't find span.myspan
   }
});
```

more of a style thing really.

Comment: Not sure why if(not){ } is better than if() return;

Comment: Wrapping the rest of the function in a conditional won't be faster than a return, and it has the drawbacks of increasing the indentation level and not working within a loop or other control structure.

Comment: Not necessarily faster to run but faster to type

Comment: Doesn't the jsPerf say that using NOT is less efficient?

Comment: Yes it does. This is why I added vaniila js. Checking for not is more sanity and it is less to type

Comment: OK of course it's faster without using a lib. But in regards to wrapping in a if NOT statement, that seems like a bad idea. Did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

It makes essentially no difference whether you use `.length` or `[0]` or any other way of checking that the selection is nonempty.  The important thing is to make sure you're searching for the element in the most efficient way, and that will depend on what you're searching for. Here are some resources on writing efficient selectors:

http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors